# Wordpress: Load only one jquery script on website

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Just about to launch a WordPress site but have noticed that it's currently loading in two jquery files, one in wp-includes and one from my `header.php`, is there a way to make wordpress load the wp-include one on the front end? Done quite a bit of search and have the only mention of this seems to include the following code, but I can't find any documentation about it, any ideas?

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of WordPress 3.3, this is the best way to do it, using the proper hook:

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Comment: Thanks looks great, am I correct in thinking this would go in my themes functions.php? Many thanks!

Comment: No problem. You're right, this goes in your themes function.php

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the following code before `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in your header.php

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
```

and you can remove other jquery includes from header.php

Comment: Thanks, however this seems to load in jquery last which in turn means that my other scripts don't initialise correctly, they are included at the bottom of the head as "<script src="/wp-content/themes/themename/js/scripts.js"></script>" any ideas?

Comment: include this line before your script includes

Comment: I currently have the following which doesn't seem to work: `<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<script src="/wp-content/themes/eog/js/jquery.ticker.js"></script>
<script src="/wp-content/themes/eog/js/jquery.cycle.lite.js"></script>
<script src="/wp-content/themes/eog/js/scripts.js"></script>`

Comment: can you check if jquery is included or not ?

Comment: it seems to be included but is loaded last when using the enqueue script

Comment: You would also want to enqueue your scripts using the same method, this way you can ensure jquery is loaded first by simply placing the enqueue script call for jquery above the one for your own script, as RonakG has demonstrated

Comment: use can just try to put the `wp_enqueue_script("jquery");` into the functions php

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Aram Mkrtchyan said, you can enqueue your scripts also using `wp_enqueue_script()`.

```
<?php
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('your_script', "path/to/your/script.js" , array('jquery'));
?>
```

The third argument to `wp_enqueue_script()` tells WordPress that `your_script` is dependent on `jquery`, so load it only after `jquery` has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to use `admin_init` hook to make it work in admin section:

```
function jquery_for_admin() {
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  return;
}

add_action('admin_init', 'jquery_for_admin');
```