# onload doesn't work in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, datepicker, onload

I created a form generated by the crm I'm using in order to find the form input in the crm. Then I pasted the code on wordpress. It works ok. Then I added a datepicker on some field and tested all of it in local. It still works ok. When I upload all the necessary on wp it doesn't work anymore.

I did some test. Here some of them:

I added the function onload to the body of the template in the file header.php but, even if in the source page there is the onload function, the datepicker doesn't show up.

I tried to write the javascript code inside the page but it doesn't work.

I tried to write < script>function-name()< /script> after the div and it is still working on local but not on wordpress.

I was afraid the problem was that my page couldn't load the file by the relative path so I used the absolute one. Nothing changed.

Eventually I tried to use the absolute path on the local file and it is still working.

The last thing I thought was: My template is ignoring the javascript. But then I realized that in the same page there are 2 other functions and they are working properly.

Here is the code, maybe we can modify that in order to achieve my aim.

```
<div id='crmWebToEntityForm' align='left' >
    <META HTTP-EQUIV='content-type' CONTENT='text/html;charset = UTF-8'>

    <form  action='https://************/crm/WebToContactForm' name=**************************** method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' onSubmit='javascript:document.charset="UTF-8"; return checkMandatery()' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
        <input type='text' style='display:none;' name='xnQsjsdp' value='*************' />
        <input type='hidden' name='zc_gad' id='zc_gad' value='' />
        <input type='text' style='display:none;' name='xmIwtLD' value='*****************' />
        <input type='text' style='display:none;' name='actionType' value='Q29udGFjdHM=' />
        <input type='text' style='display:none;' name='returnURL' value='*************************************' />
        <input type='text' style='display:none;' maxlength='20' name='CONTACTCF7' value='Applicant'/>
         <div id="cf-two-columns">
           <div id="left">
               <p>First Name *<br /><input type='text' style='width:250px;'  maxlength='40' name='First Name' /></p>

 <p>Last Name *<br /><input type='text' style='width:250px;' maxlength='80' name='Last Name' /></p>
              <p>Date Of Birth *<br /><input id="datepickr" readonly="readonly"  type="text" style="width:250px;" maxlength="20" name="Date of Birth" placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy"></p>



             <p>Email *<br /><input type='email' style='width:250px;' maxlength='40' name='Email' /></p>
               <p>Phone *<br /><input type='text'style='width:250px;' maxlength='50' name='Phone' /></p>
               <p> * These fields are required <br /></p>
           </div>
           <div id="right">
               <p>Address* <br /><input type='text' style='width:250px;' maxlength='250' name='Mailing Street' /></p>
               <p>Suburb or city* <br /><input type='text' style='width:250px;' maxlength='30' name='Mailing City' /></p>
               <p>Postcode* <br /><input type='text' style='width:250px;' maxlength='30' name='Mailing Zip' /></p>
                <p>Country* <br />
                <select style='width:250px;' name='Mailing Country'>
                    <option value='Select One'>Select one</option>
                    <option value='Afghanistan'>Afghanistan</option>
                    <option value='Albania'>Albania</option>
                    <option value='Algeria'>Algeria</option>

                </select>
               </p>
               <p>State* <br />
                    <select style='width:250px;' name='CONTACTCF9'>
                        <option value='Select One'>Select one</option>
                        <option value='Western Australia'>Western Australia</option>
                        <option value='New South Wales'>New South Wales</option>
                        <option value='Queensland'>Queensland</option>
                        <option value='ACT'>ACT</option>
                        <option value='South Australia'>South Australia</option>
                        <option value='Northern Territory'>Northern Territory</option>
                        <option value='Off Shore'>I am outside Australia</option>
                    </select>
               </p>

            </div>
           <div id="right1">
               <p>Current VISA*<br />
               <select onchange="showDiv(this)" id="CONTACTCF1" style='width:250px;' name='CONTACTCF1'>
                        <option value='Select One'>Select one</option>
                        <option value='Bridging'>Bridging</option>
                        <option value='DeFacto'>DeFacto</option>
                        <option value='Partner'>Partner</option>
                        <option value='Permanent'>Permanent</option>
                        <option value='Sponsored'>Sponsored</option>
                        <option value='Student'>Student</option>
                        <option value='Tourist'>Tourist</option>
                        <option value='Working Holiday'>Working Holiday</option>
                        <option value='2 Working Holiday'>2 Working Holiday</option>
                        <option value='Business application'>Business application</option>
                    </select>
               </p>

<p id="hide" style="display: none;">VISA Expiry Date *<br /><input readonly type='text' id="CONTACTCF81" style='width:250px;' maxlength='20' name='CONTACTCF81' placeholder='dd/MM/yyyy' />
</p>


<script>
function showDiv(elem){
   if(elem.value == 'Bridging') {
      document.getElementById('hide').style.display = "none";
} else if(elem.value == 'Select One') {
document.getElementById('hide').style.display = "none";
}
else {
document.getElementById('hide').style.display = "block";
}
}
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Passport Number *<br /><input type='text' style='width:250px;' maxlength='15' name='CONTACTCF2' /></p>
               <p>Passport Expiry Date *<br /><input readonly id="datepickr2" type='text' style='width:250px;' maxlength='15' name='CONTACTCF84' placeholder='dd/MM/yyyy' /></p>
<p>Nationality *<br /><input type='text' style='width:250px;' maxlength='20' name='CONTACTCF3' /></p>
            </div>
           <div id="right2">
               <p>Passport Upload *<br /><input type='file' name='theFile'></input></p>
               <br>
               <p>Enter this code<br /></p>
               <p><img id='imgid' style="border:1px solid black;" src='*****************************************'>
               <a href='javascript:;' onclick='reloadImg()'>Reload</a></p><br />
               <p><input type='text' style='width:250px;' maxlength='80' name='enterdigest' /></p><br />
               <p><input class="wpcf7-submit" style='font-size:12px;color:black' type='submit'  value='Submit' /> </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var mndFileds = new Array('First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email', 'Phone', 'Date of Birth', 'Mailing Street', 'Mailing City', 'Mailing Zip', 'Mailing Country', 'CONTACTCF2', 'CONTACTCF3', 'CONTACTCF81', 'CONTACTCF1', 'CONTACTCF84', 'CONTACTCF9');
            var fldLangVal = new Array('First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email', 'Phone', 'Date of Birth', 'Mailing Street', 'Mailing City', 'Mailing Zip', 'Mailing Country', 'Passport Number', 'Nationality', 'Visa Expiry Date', 'Current visa', 'Passport Expiry Date', 'State');
            function reloadImg() {
                if (document.getElementById('imgid').src.indexOf('&d') !== -1) {
                    document.getElementById('imgid').src = document.getElementById('imgid').src.substring(0, document.getElementById('imgid').src.indexOf('&d')) + '&d' + new Date().getTime();
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('imgid').src = document.getElementById('imgid').src + '&d' + new Date().getTime();
                }
            }
            function checkMandatery() {
                var name = '';
                var email = '';
                for (i = 0; i < mndFileds.length; i++) {
                    var fieldObj = document.forms['WebToContacts1328094000000077001'][mndFileds[i]];
                    if (fieldObj) {
                        if (((fieldObj.value).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')).length == 0) {
                            alert(fldLangVal[i] + ' cannot be empty');
                            fieldObj.focus();
                            return false;
                        } else if (fieldObj.nodeName == 'SELECT') {
                            if (fieldObj.options[fieldObj.selectedIndex].value == '-None-') {
                                alert(fldLangVal[i] + ' cannot be none');
                                fieldObj.focus();
                                return false;
                            }
                        } else if (fieldObj.type == 'checkbox') {
                            if (fieldObj.checked == false) {
                                alert('Please accept  ' + fldLangVal[i]);
                                fieldObj.focus();
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        try {
                            if (fieldObj.name == 'Last Name') {
                                name = fieldObj.value;
                            }
                        } catch (e) {}
                    }
                }
                try {
                    if ($***) {
                        var firstnameObj = document.forms['WebToContacts1328094000000077001']['First Name'];
                        if (firstnameObj) {
                            name = firstnameObj.value + ' ' + name;
                        }
                        $***.salesiq.visitor.name(name);
                        var emailObj = document.forms['WebToContacts1328094000000077001']['Email'];
                        if (emailObj) {
                            email = emailObj.value;
                            $***.salesiq.visitor.email(email);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e) {}
            }
</script>
    </form>

</div>

                    <script src="http://getyourvisa.com.au/datepicker/codebase/dhtmlxcalendar.js"></script>
              <script>
        var myCalendar;
        function doOnLoad() {
            myCalendar = new dhtmlXCalendarObject(["datepickr","CONTACTCF81","datepickr2"]);
        }
    </script>
```

[HERE](http://www.getyourvisa.com.au/pippo/) is also a live preview.

Thank you in advance to everyone who will try to help.
DD

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to get tips on how to ask. For one, DO remove unnecessary code from your example. For example 3 options in the drop down would have been sufficient

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestion. I deleted the options but I kept the whole code because I'm not sure which one could be the problem.

Comment: Where is the onload and how did you add it to the body? Never use `<body onload="..">` but do use the jQuery now you installed it. I do not see where you call doOnload. Instead do `$(function() { .... });`

Comment: Do you mean to use the ready() function? I don't know javascript... I just followed the instructions to attach the datapicker to the form...

Comment: $(function() { doOnLoad() }); like this? and where should i put this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial:
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Maybe you can revise your code and insert the one in the tutorial.

Comment: Please do not post comments as answers until you have enough rep to do so. It is not that hard to get

Comment: I already used that one and it was working good but I cannot choose the year and if someone for example qas born in 1977 should go back too much month by month

Comment: Actually it seems you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865218/jquery-ui-datepicker-set-year-range-dropdown-to-100-years

Comment: mmm interesting. I'm going to try

Answer (score 0):

1. **You have FAR too many jQuery loaded. You need to have it only ONCE.
   This is breaking your picker**.  If I search the net for [Load jQuery Once wordpress](https://www.google.come/search?q=only%20load%20jquery%20once%20wordpress) I get answers like

   - [Wordpress: Load only one jquery script on website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787064/wordpress-load-only-one-jquery-script-on-website)
   - http://electrokami.com/coding/wordpress-multiple-jquery-inclusion-fix/

If you do not know how to remove these, you need to get assistance from a WP developer. I am not one, sorry.

2. To load the datepicker onload, use this

-

```
var myCalendar;
$(function() {
  myCalendar = new dhtmlXCalendarObject(["datepickr","CONTACTCF81","datepickr2"]);
});
```

instead of

```
var myCalendar;
function doOnLoad() {
   myCalendar = new dhtmlXCalendarObject(["datepickr","CONTACTCF81","datepickr2"]);
}
```

and remove the doOnload from anywhere else

Comment: Still not working... I know there are many issues but i just copied and pasted the code given by the crm.

Comment: You have more than one jQuery loaded. You need to get rid of all but one

Comment: Thank for your help... Unfortunately I am still not able to make that code works.. probably I'm makeing some mistakes. I insert the whole code but nothing changed. What else should I do?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You need to remove all but one jQuery.js - that is your main problem. I think I counted 3 or more. The fiddle I wrote was to prove the datepicker worked with the code I suggested

Comment: Hi thank you again. Unfortunately my template seems to load jquery everywhere. I  don't know how to fix it. there is any walk around? for example put the form as an iframe or something like that?

Comment: so you discourage me to do that? if yes am I left other options?

Comment: It's ok as long as you know it is not solving the main issue and you may get the same problem again